Proving that if semidecidable, then computable
Definition: The graph of an n-ary function F is the n+1-ary relation $G_F$ defined by $G_F(a_1,...,a_n,b) \Leftrightarrow F(a_1,...,a_n)=b$.
Theorem: if $G_F$ is semidecidable, then $F$ is computable.
Proof: By the definition of the graph, if $b$ is F's output on input $(a_1,...,a_n)$ then the tuple $(a_1,...,a_n,b)$ is in $G_F$.
If we assume, that $F$ gives output for all tuples $(a_1,...,a_n)$, then the algorithm is as follows:
input a1,...,an
x = 1
while True:
    for (b = 0; b <= x; b++):
        run G_F(a1,...,an,b) for <= x iterations
        if the output is Yes, return b
    x++

The problem with this proof for me is the above assumption. What if $F$ is not defined for some input? Then this algorithm will not terminate, and therefore $F$ is not computable by this algorithm.

If $F$ is undefined on some input, then a program that computes $F$ should not terminate on that input, so this is fine. Review the definition of a computable partial function.

@NaïmFavier, that sounds like an answer to the question.  Can I encourage you to write that in the 'Your Answer' box, instead of as a comment, so we can upvote it and so the question can be treated as answered?  The site format discourages answering in the comments.  No need to write any more than that.
